# Export Gridview To Excel File - Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, export-to-excel, error-correction

i use this `code for exporting gridview to Excel in asp.net - c#`.....but i  `found some error in my code`

i am using `stored procedure` for `sql command` and my code behind is as follows....

**C# code** load event (`Calling GetData method`)

```
   public partial class Admin_ResultDisplay : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnect"].ConnectionString);
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)Session["sqlcmd"];
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }
```

here `GetData() Method`

```
private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnect"].ConnectionString;
    //SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

    Session["sqlcmd"] = cmd;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  // <= ERROR POINTED HERE....
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        cn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

> RAHUL:

As per your guidence i make changes but still gives error....

And `ERROR` Something like this...it has null value at page_load event thats why it gives error......

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: ofcourse, you have not declared SqlCommand cmd; before the DataTable dt = GetData(cmd); `//(gives error here) cmd is not exist in current context`. Also i suggest you declare  private DataTable GetData() rather than  private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's beacuse you are defining `cmd` in button event as below which is local in scope. If you need it globally then try defining accordingly.

```
protected void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
 {
 try
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetExamResults", cn);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to `cmd` in page_load as well then you can call the SP again in page_load and use it. Like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {   
   cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings     
   ["DbConnect"].ConnectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetExamResults", cn);
```

But suggest you store the `cmd` value in session ans reuse it again in page_load like,  where your use of `cmd` getting over

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
// Your code goes here

Session["sqlcmd"] = cmd;
```

In page_load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)Session["sqlcmd"];
```

Then use `cmd` in page_load as well per your need

Comment: rahul - thanx for your guidence....i tried it with globally but i needs parameters of **GetExamResults** procedure ?? so how can i do it ?? give me a sample solution so i can understand...

Comment: Rahul - As per your guidence i make changes but still gives error...it has null value at page_load event thats why it gives error......**Object reference not set to an instance of an object** `I have make changes in my question` you can see it...

Comment: did you store the cmd value to session? Pleaseput a break point and see what getting stored in `session["sqlcmd"]`.

Comment: Rahul - it takes nothing directly gives error message....see my edits in questions what i did ?? if any mistake in my code then tell me...

Comment: You need to store cmd in session @ button event code block once you are all done with cmd. Again, in your `Getdata()` method you are storing cmd in session but I don't see you defining cmd in that code block.

Answer (score 0):

The error is giving you the information that you need.  cmd does, indeed, not exist then.  You need to create an instance of SqlCommand in your Page_Load event.  From the code you have provided, you are only defining cmd in the button event which is not available to the Page_Load event.

Comment: CM Kanode - so in which place i have to make changes ??

Comment: You need to create an instance of SqlCommand in your Page_Load event.  Also, the change that you made based on Rahul's suggestion is incomplete.  You are using the session variable, but did you actually create the session variable first?